# Multires modifier and geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, multiresolution

I have sculpted a model using the `Multiresolution` modifier. This lead to pretty dense topology. Now I would like to use a `Geometry Nodes` setup to put scales on some parts of my model, however there are way to many vertices now.

Is there a way to tell the geometry nodes to use the base mesh without any modifiers applied?

Alternatively is there a way to simplify the mesh within my geometry nodes setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not possible, unfortunately.

Theoretically this would work, but if you use the modifier *Multiresolution*, unfortunately not.

This modifier always needs the original and unchanged data of an object, and is therefore always at the top of your modifier chain.

In *Geometry Nodes* you have no possibility to process this original data in the same object after this modifier.

And unfortunately, there is currently no way to reduce a mesh of this type with *Geometry Nodes*.

You could remove individual vertices, edges or faces, but that would destroy the topology of your mesh.